# Way to send hover affect atop a <div>?

Tags: html, css, hover, background-image

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the hover effect that I currently have on the home page of my website to be placed atop the background images that I have set for each of the page's interactive boxes.

So basically, the color-based hover effects should take affect atop the background images, which isn't the current case. As you can see for boxes 1 and 3, every time you hover over, the color changes. I would like this to be true for all of the boxes that also have images. As I have it, I can't figure out a way to bring the hover effect to the top of the stack.

Basically, from the code posted below, I think I need

```
.col-md-4:hover{
    background-color: #FFE097;
}
```

to supersede the 's for the boxes I set on the main page.

Here is my main CSS:

```
.col-md-4 {
    color:#00A5D1;
    height:300px;
    border: 1px solid #FF8B6F;
}
.col-md-4:hover{
    background-color: #FFE097;
}
.col-md-4 h3 {
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* Basic Structure
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Buernard', Garamond, "Buenard", "EB Garamond",'EB Garamond';
}
```

And here is the HTML for my home page:

```
<style>
    h3 {
        font-size:36px;
        font-style: bold;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:'Buernard', Garamond, "Buenard", "EB Garamond",'EB Garamond';
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;   
    }
    #div1 {
            background-image: url('');
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            background: url('bgimage.jpg') no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
    #div2 {
            background-image: url('FeatherPen2.jpg');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: contain; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    #div3 {
            background-image: url('');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    #div4 {
            background-image: url('Birds%20on%20Wire.jpg');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: contain; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    #div5 {
            background-image: url('Shark Cans Logo.jpg');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    #div6 {
            background-image: url('Ocean%20Water2.jpg');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 110%;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    #div7 {
            background-image: url('Piano.jpg');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    #div8 {
            background-image: url('Gallery%20Image.JPG');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    #div9 {
            background-image: url('Handshake.png');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 72%;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    div {
        background-image:url(../images/please-dont-use-spaces.jpg); //add the background image
        background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
        background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
    }
    </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <a href="About.html" title="About the site and Author"><div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>About</h3>
                    </div></a>
                <a href="Articles.html" title="Original Articles and Content"><div class="col-md-4" id='div2'>
                    <h3>Articles</h3>
                </div>
                <a href="Coding Corner.html" title="Coding Corner - Code for a Variety of Projects"><div class="col-md-4" id="">
                    <h3>Coding Corner</h3>
                </div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="Contact - Social.html" title="Contact The Floodplains & The FloodShark"><div class="col-md-4" id="div4">
                  <h3>Contact & Social</h3>
                </div></a>
                <a href="The FloodShark Main.html" title="The FloodShark Music and Media"><div class="col-md-4" id="div5">
                    <h3>
                    The FloodShark
                    Music
                    </h3>
                </div></a>
                <a href="Floodplain Productions.html" title="Floodplain Productions - virtual record label"><div class="col-md-4" id="div6">
                    <h3>Floodplain Productions</h3>
                </div></a>
            </div>  
            <div class="row">   
                <a href="Classical Corner.html" title="Classical Corner - A nook dedicated to sharing and categorizing classical music"><div class="col-md-4" id="div7">
                    <h3>Classical Corner</h3>
                </div></a>
                <a href="Gallery.html" title="Images, Photographs, and Album Art"><div class="col-md-4" id="div8">
                    <h3>Gallery</h3>
                </div></a>
                <a href="Contribute - Support - Donate.html" title="Contribute to The Floodplains!"><div class="col-md-4" id="div9">
                    <h3>Contribute / Support</h3>
                </div></a>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the overlay using a pseudoelement stacked on top of the `div`.

Add the following CSS:

```
.col-md-4 {
  ...
  position: relative;
}

.col-md-4:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #FFE097;
  opacity: 0;
}

.col-md-4:hover:after {
  opacity: .5;
}

.col-md-4 h3 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  ...
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhucg651/2/)